# angularJS ng-model input type number to rootScope not updating

Tags: angularjs

I have an input type number set to

```
<input type="number" ng-model="inputModel"/>
```

Where `inputModel` is `$rootScope.inputModel`. Every time I change the input box the value does not persist onto the `$rootScope`. Is it not possible to bind an input box to a `$rootScope`? what am I missing here? 
I basically have another controller that performs calculations on given `$rootScope` and those calculations change depending on what the value of the input box is.
 
An help is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Your problem is with prototypical inheritance. This question comes up a lot on Stack Overflow. Check out [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance) for explanation of what's wrong here.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller said it all. Check also this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/UXsLj/). It may help...

Comment: ideally you should not be storing anything on the $rootScope. A service should be used to communicate between controllers. Check [this video out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXpHV5gWgyk)

Comment: Is your `<input...>` inside an ng-controller?  If so, then an `inputModel` primitive property will be created on that ng-controller's scope when you type into the text field.  This new property will hide/shadow the $rootScope property of the same name.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments. yes indeed as josh and mark mentioned its regarding inheritance that this doesn't work as expected. I tried doing $parent on the ng-model but that didn't work either when updated... switching all of my stuff into services to to see if that helps

Answer (score 28):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope) - you can use the `$root` property on the scope and the binding would be

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$root.inputModel"/>
```

This will bind directly on the root scope without the need to explicitly assign it in the controller.

Answer (score 18):

As others pointed out, it is a prototypical inheritance problem. Your input model is generated in the current scope, not the rootScope.

Always use "." in your views. This will work:

```
rootScope.fields = {
    inputModel: ''
}
```

and

```
<input type="number" ng-model="fields.inputModel"/>
```