# What is the difference between $scope.$root and $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I see in controllers that $scope has $root, what is this? How is it different from $rootScope which can be injected in the controller?

Comment: I have never come accross `$scope.$root`. It could be any user-defined property defined on `$scope`.

Comment: nope its not user defined. you can find it in $scope of any controller

Comment: And a user defined property should never start with '$'

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`$rootScope` var which points to the parent of all the scopes and can be injected everywhere. All other scopes are children of the `$rootScope`. They are created via the `$new` method of the `$rootScope` thus every scope inherits from the `$rootScope`.

In the angular source in the definition of the `Scope` constructor  [there is a line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ecab775ceefcd55a23780d005ce1c39cd8651b/src/ng/rootScope.js#L130) :

```
 function Scope() {
   this.$id = nextUid();
 ...
 this['this'] = this.$root =  this;
 ...
```

It seems the `$root` var is just a placeholder for `this` of the first scope created - `$rootScope`.

Next there is [this piece of code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ecab775ceefcd55a23780d005ce1c39cd8651b/src/ng/rootScope.js#L180) in the `$new` method:

```
  $new: function(isolate) {
      ...

    if (isolate) {
      child = new Scope();
      child.$root = this.$root;
   ...
   return child;
```

So the `$root` var of every scope child of `$rootScope` is a reference to `$rootScope`. And all the children of those children will get the same reference to `$rootScope`

In my opinion it is better to use the `$rootScope` via dependency injection because it is an explicit and overall more frequently used way of referring to the `$rootScope`

Comment: Nice explanation. I think $scope.$root is there, for easy access to $rootScope variables inside templates, without the need of including $rootScope into the controller.

Comment: @canerbalci in angular 1.4, root scope is allowed to be destroyed, use this.$root will point to null after root scope be destroyed

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned before, `$scope.$root` holds a reference to the `$rootScope`.

Unfortunately, there IS a difference between using `$scope.$root` and using `$rootScope`:

1. When `$scope` IS the root, its `$root` property is `null`
2. `$scope.$root` is only assigned on isolate scopes:
   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.6/src/ng/rootScope.js#L204

So you might have a situation where `$scope.$root` is `null`.
Better use `$rootScope` instead...

Comment: That's one of the reasons you should never pass `$rootScope` somewhere (for example angular-ui modals) directly but always use a child scope `$rootScope.$new();`

Comment: Wrong. `$root` [will be there](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.6/src/ng/rootScope.js#L135) anyway.

Comment: @PetrPeller Can you explain more or direct me to more info. I think I am running into a issue that is being caused by $rootScope being injected into a modal. Thanks.

Comment: @Usagi It's been a while. I would recommend using `$rootScope` as few as possible. If you need to share information between components just use a service. When injecting a scope always create a new child: `$scope.$new()` to prevent bugs. Components might try to `$destroy` the scope to clean-up when unmounted or set some internal information. That's why every component needs it's own `$scope` instance.