# Use rootScope variables in my html

Tags: angularjs

So we can use scope variables in our angular html easily like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So for example:

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

Is using `yourName` from the scope I was hoping to do:

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}} you are in in {{$rootScope.zoneName}}!</h1>
```

Is it possible to bring `$rootScope` variables in like this?

Comment: from every $scope you can access to the root scope using `$scope.$root` as  this answer states -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533886/903998

Answer (score 93):

You do not need to specify `$rootScope` in html. You can use it the same way as you use `$scope` variables

Just update from

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}} you are in in {{$rootScope.zoneName}}!</h1>
```

to

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}} you are in in {{zoneName}}!</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you nikhil I didnt know that! Will test out right away! :) Does the same apply to if I wanted to inline variables from `$route.current.params` ?

Comment: Im trying but i have some error somewhere which is disabling the app Im trying to find haha

Comment: Thanks so much nikhil!

Comment: Oh forgot the scope inheritance, that's even better

Comment: Great answer. Works perfect.

Comment: If this answers your question, the best way to thank @nikhil is by accepting it as an answer to reward his efforts.

Comment: That won't work in isolated scopes of directives. You need to use $root.yourVariable

Comment: @IsraGab - Agreed. However, the OP was stuck with a simplistic scenario and hence, a simplistic answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I needed to use {{$root.zoneName}} instead. You know why?

Comment: @JeffPal - Were you trying to use this in directive template?

Answer (score 87):

This should work:

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}} you are in in {{$root.zoneName}}!</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you Gpicazo! woudl same work for `{{$route.current.params}}`?

Comment: @yatg I don't believe so. You can however, (1) inject $stateParams into the controller (2) set a scope variable like $scope.param = $stateParams.param; and (3)  bind the scope variable in the view: {{param}}.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope for explanation

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Was not able to access the variable suffix from the DOM without `$root`.

Comment: @mjoyce91 - I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 13):

you could inject `$rootScope` in you controller and then map it to a scope variable like this

`$scope.global = $rootScope;`

then in your template you could use

`<p>$rootscope value of name is {{ global.name }}.</p>`

You have to be careful to not uselessly put thing into the `$rootScope` as it's not considered the best practice to modulate your code

Answer (score 12):

I know this is late, But a good explanation is needed !

Any View in **Angular 1.x** world will have automatically and by default a new **$scope**such **$scope** will be extended from something called the **$rootScope** so the local **$scope** will inherit everything that the **$rootScope** is storing and will have it's own version of the that data.

So if you have any information in the **$rootScope** level you will have it by default and so your view can access it directly using usual interpolation.

This line of code will show the how too !

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.persons = [
     {
       name : "Houssem",
       role : "Developer Advocate"
     },
     {
       name: "Clark",
       role: "Developer"
     }
  ];
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.greetings = 'Hello World !';
});
```

And this on the Index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
 <script data-require="ui-router@1.0.0-alpha.5" data-semver="1.0.0-alpha.5" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.5/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <p>{{greetings}}</p>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
         <p>{{person.name}} - {{person.role}}</p>
       </li>
     </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

And please check This [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/t9l5e0) which explain just that !

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was not working with using `rootscope` variables directly. I had to use it with $root.

my code looks like below:

```
<h1>you are in in {{$root.zoneName}}!</h1>
```