# Why should I use $rootScope if I can use $scope.$root?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

Since `$scope.$root` is a reference to `$rootScope` and therefore the same thing, why should I bother injecting `$rootScope` when I need to use it if I already have access to it through `$scope.$root`? What are the reasons, whether they are AngularJS best practices or general programming best practices, of using `$rootScope` over `$scope.$root`?

For clarity, this is *not* a question about when to use `$rootScope`. It's asking *why* I should use it.

Comment: What in the world is $root.$scope?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Thanks, I will edit that...

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope

Comment: This has already been answered:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope)

Comment: ^ this has already been answered (posted this a few seconds before you @flyer :P)

Comment: Except it's not a duplicate because I already know the difference. I'm asking what is the purpose of using $rootScope _at all_.

What is the purpose of injecting something if it's already accessible through `$scope.$root`

Answer (score 1):

**$rootScope**: var which points to the parent of all the scopes and can be injected everywhere. All other scopes are children of the $rootScope. They are created via the $new method of the $rootScope thus every scope inherits from the $rootScope.

**$scope.$root**: holds a reference to the $rootScope.

There Is a difference between using $scope.$root and using $rootScope:

When $scope Is the root, its $root property is null

$scope.$root is only assigned on isolate scopes
So you might have a situation where $scope.$root is null. Better use $rootScope instead...

Comment: The bit about `$root` being null when `$scope` is `$rootScope` isn't true. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.11/src/ng/rootScope.js#L178

Comment: *$scope.$root is only assigned on isolate scopes*... and prototypically inherited otherwise. There's no way how $scope.$root may be null in normal conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use `$rootScope` in your application. Like you mentioned, `$scope.$root` is simply a reference to `$rootScope` from your current `$scope`. If you're going to be referencing the root scope, you should inject and use `$rootScope` since it is an explicit declaration of the top-level `$scope`.

However, in general, AngularJS best practices usually lead the developer to stray away from using `$rootScope`. Although it is convenient to have a global scope that can be injected anywhere in your application, it is typically overused and abused causing too many objects to be on the `$rootScope` objects which can lead to slower performance in larger AngularJS applications.

Typically when I'm thinking about using `$rootScope` to globally hold something, I stop and think for a minute as to what a better approach might be. Perhaps a better solution could involve injecting a shared service/factory around instead of relying on the `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste to some degree, since it's a known fact that `$rootScope === $scope.$root`, even though `$rootScope` is tiny bit more performant and minifies better.

In modern AngularJS apps `$scope` isn't used much. `$scope` isn't always available in controllers with controllerAs syntax, including component controllers. `$scope` isn't available in services, too.

`$rootScope` is conventionally used instead of `$scope.$root` when root scope should be referred, for the sake of consistency.